# onLongItemClick affects recycled views

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view which loads items from an arrayList, the problem comes in when using the `onLongClickItemListener`
Whenever an item is long clicked I show a hidden layout in that item itself. So whenever the list is recycling items, the hidden layout would be visible for items that are recycled (which are supposed to not show the layout).

Any ideas? I've tried to add a flag to the object itself of each item in the list with no luck, the most I could get is to make the layout gone for every item that is shown when scrolling, but I want to keep the opened ones by the user stay visible.

Here's my current code:

```
 messageListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
                if (ll.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    msgs.get(position).setViewFlag(false);
                    msgAdapter.setMessages(msgs);
                } else {
                    ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    msgs.get(position).setViewFlag(true);
                    msgAdapter.setMessages(msgs);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

And here's the code for the adapter:

```
 public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static int lastPos = -1;
        private ArrayList<Message> messages;
        private Context context;



    public MessagesAdapter(ArrayList<Message> messages, Context context) {
        this.messages = messages;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.message_list_row, null);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgTitle);
            viewHolder.body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.msgBody);
            viewHolder.monthDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.monthDate);
            viewHolder.dayDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayDate);
            viewHolder.status = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusIcon);
            viewHolder.linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hiddenLayout);
            viewHolder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        if (!(messages.get(position).isViewFlag()))
            holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.title.setText(messages.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.body.setText(messages.get(position).getBody());
        switch (messages.get(position).getMessageType()) {
            case READ:
                holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yellowcircle);
                break;
            case UNREAD:
                holder.status.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redcircle);
                break;
        }
        lastPos = position;
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return messages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView title;
        public TextView body;
        public TextView dayDate;
        public TextView monthDate;
        public ImageView status;
        public TextView read;
        public TextView unread;
        public TextView remove;
        public TextView reply;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

    }

    public void setMessages(ArrayList<Message> msgs) {
        this.messages = msgs;
    }

}
```

Comment: you have to add a boolean flag in `Message` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to modify the visibility of the views inside the `ListView` directly. As a general pattern, you need to update the data that is backing up the `ListView` - the messages array in your case. You would need to set the isViewFlag property in your `Message` rather than trying to change the visibility on a view that you don't control on which item is being used.

Your click handler would just do (and follow the changes in the adapter as well):

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    msgAdapter.setExpandedPosition(msgAdapter.getExpandedPosition() == position ? -1 : position);
    return true;
}
```

However, since this is a UI state that doesn't really depend on the properties on your item, but rather based on the user interaction with the UI, one might argue (me included) that this information does not belong in there. I would set a property in the adapter (if only one item can be in the expended state at a particular time) or a list of properties like a sparse array (if multiple items can be in the expended state at the same moment in time).

Your adapter would be something like (also please not the changes to your original `getItemId()` and `setMessages()` which don't have anything to do with the problem in hand, but are just good practice):

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // for Option1 - only one item expanded at a time
    int expandedPos = -1;
    ....

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ....
        //Option 1 - only one item expanded at a time
        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(position == expandedPos ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        //Option 2 - multiple items can be expanded at the same time, following your current implementation
        holder.linearLayout.setVisibility(messages.get(position).isViewFlag() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        ....
    }

    public void setExpandedPosition(int position) {
        //Option 1 - only one item expanded at a time
        expandedPos = position;

        //Option 2 - multiple items can be expanded at the same time, following your current implementation
        messages.get(position).setIsViewFlag(position != -1);

        // In both cases:
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    // only for Option 1 - only one item expanded at a time
    public int getExpandedPosition() {
        return expandedPos;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public void setMessages(ArrayList<Message> msgs) {
        this.messages = msgs;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```